# Access JSON content instead of header

Tags: json, meteor

I'm trying to parse some JSON data with Meteor on the server. I'm using `Meteor.http.call("GET")` etc and I get data back great. However, I only seem to have easy access to data that is included in the `headers` and `data` (seen from printing the retrieve data to the console). However, the data I really want access to is under the `content` but not sure how to get at it.

For something under the `data` I simply `var = jsonReturned['data']` and I get whatever JSON that contains, and I can keep narrowing down as needed `['data']['media']`, however this doesn't work with the `content` side of things.

I'm not overly familiar with JSON API requests so I may be missing something obvious. The content data is also easily seen by just browsing to the requested URL as well so I'm definitely getting the JSON data.

Comment: When you console.log the data coming from the GET request, you see "content" in what's being logged? Maybe a screenshot of the console.log output if so?

Comment: I see 3 main headings, `header` `data` and `content` . `Header` has obvious header type stuff like date, format returned etc, `data` has some of the information that I want, and `content` is just a long string of JSON formatted text, that contains the rest of the info I want

Comment: You may need to use JSON.Parse to unstringify' your data

Comment: JSON.parse did exactly what I needed with the content, thanks Sgnl